# How can I fix a bathtub refinishing debacle?

Tags: bathtub, repainting

OK.  So I have an old cast iron white bathtub.  And it was in really bad shape.  Nicks, worn out, everything.

So I go to HD looking for the [Rust-Oleum tub & tile refinishing kit](http://www.rustoleum.com/CBGProduct.asp?pid=116).  Didn't have it, but they suggested the HOMAX variant.  So I got the [Homax white brush on](http://orders.homaxproducts.com/Featured-Product/Tough-As-Tile-Refinishing-Paint-Brush-On-White).  Basically it is liquid epoxy (not sure it is epoxy since there was no additive for chemical reaction).

Well first of all I bought white and it isn't white - I may be able to live with the almond color....   But the biggest problem is that it is a gloppy mess.  After the second coat it seemed to look ok.  But then an hour or two later I went in and looked and it is horrible.  It pooled up in some places.  Other place it didn't cover well...  On a scale of 1 to 10 you wouldn't give it a 1.

I read the reviews for Homax and this seems to be the norm.  Sucks.  Didn't know.  So what are my next steps?  The tub is a huge uneven mess.  And when I say uneven - you could probably notice from 50 feet.  I have basically remodeled my whole house and this is the first thing that I have messed up. I can't touch it for another 2 days and really need this bathroom working next week.

Comment: And I have used the rust-oleum brand resurfacing before and it worked well.  Now I would have to say that the other tubs where not in this bad of shape...

Comment: If it's truly epoxy, I don't think you'll have much luck getting it off short of grinding it all out. If you have the time/energy, I suppose that's an option. At this point, it might be saner to just go find a different tub and replace it.

Comment: I don't mind replacing a tub but I just laid new tile on floor and tub surround...  This soundlike it would be a nightmare to knock out and replace while not killing the tile job.

Comment: You may not need to completely remove it, only achieve an even uniform surface. Still not easy. Thinking out of the box, look at what's possible in auto body work. Once the surface is even, apply a proper resurfacing product. I wonder, can this product be applied over bondo?

Comment: Angle grinder with sandpaper flap discs.. Should be able to work through grits. Once you get to 150-180, try an autobody primer on any bare metal spots.  It will give you a sense whether further grits are needed.

Comment: @bcworkz bondo should work if needed.  Its a specialized epoxy.  I would prime any bare metal before bondoing.

Comment: Your experience was similar to mine with every Behr product I've tried (HD's in-house brand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was paint thinner and lots of razors.  This stuff was such crap that after paint thinner sat on some parts and it came off like latex paint.

Answer (score 3):

Acetone.  Acetone breaks it down into a consistency of Elmer's glue but very gooey.  Then I took a paint scraper razor blade and it peels similiar to latex paint but a little tougher. I'm not quit finished because I ran out of acetone.  Once off, I will have to see if I can get the tub to its original state. If not, I'll order Rustoleum online. I used it years ago, and it came out great! Homax should be called Homewreck.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.